# MongoDB Syntax error: What is the proper syntax for aggregate and group?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use Aggregate and $group to do an averaging.

But I am having this error "Error: Line 5: Unexpected token }"

I am struggling to get the correct brackets in place. Appreciate if anyone can assist.

```
db.db1.aggregate([
        {$match:{"budget":"medium"}},
        {$group:{
            "_id":{"budget":"$budget"},
            "AvgBirthYear":{$avg:{"$birth_year"}}
                }
         }
         ])
```

My raw data is like this[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$avg:{"$birth_year"}` isn't valid, you probably meant `$avg: "$birth_year"`

Also, you're only matching documents where the field `"budget"` is `"medium"` so you'll only get one group, is that intended?

Also, `"_id":{"budget":"$budget"}` works but can be simplified to `"_id": "$budget"`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
db.db1.aggregate([
        {
           $match:{
                "budget":"medium"
           }
        },
        {
           $group:{
             "_id":"$budget",
             "AvgBirthYear":{ $avg: "$birth_year" }
           }
        }
])
```